# Verification: Prove $\theta$ is a congruence on unary algebra $ \underline{A} $ with subuniverse $B$

Tags: proof-verification, universal-algebra

Let $\underline{A}$ be a unary algebra with $B$ as a subuniverse and define $\theta$ as $a\theta b$ iff $a = b$ or $\{a,b\} \subseteq B$

Equivalence Relation:

Reflexive :
let $a \in B$ $a=a$ so $a \theta a$

Symmetry: 
let $a,b \in B$ and assume $a\theta b$
then $a=b $ or ${a,b} \subseteq B$ so we have $b=a$ or $\{b,a\} \subseteq B$ thus $b\theta a$

Transitive:
let $a,b,c \in B$ and $a\theta b$ and $b \theta c$ then $a = b = c \implies a=c$ or $\{a,b\},\{b,c\}\subseteq B \implies \{a,c\} \subseteq \{a,b,c\} \subseteq B \implies \{a,c\} \subseteq B $ thus $a\theta c$

We get that $\theta $ is an equivalence relation.

Now, $B$ is assumed to be a subuniverse of $\underline{A}$ hence for all operations in $\underline{A}$ we know $B$ is closed under them.

Consider, $a,b \in B$ such that $a \theta b$ and let $f$ be a unary function in $\underline{A}$:

Case 1: $a=b$ then $f(a) = f(b)$ thus $f(a) \theta f(b)$

Case 2: $\{a,b\} \subseteq B$ as $B$ is closed under all fundamental operations in the algebra thus we know $f(a), f(b) \in B$ thus $\{f(a),f(b)\} \subseteq B$

Therefore, $\theta$ is a congruence on $\underline{A}$

This seems pretty straightforward but I want to make sure I am doing this correctly.

Comment: The title says you want a congruence relation on $A$, but your whole alleged proof is only about elements of $B$.

Comment: (minor) Also the "mixed" cases are missing in the proof of transitivity.

Comment: @AndreasBlass $B$ is a subuniverse of $\underline{A}$ so if I take $B = A$ the underlying set of $\underline{A}$ then that should take care of that, should it not?

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf the mixed cases?

Comment: If you take $B=A$ then you're dealing only with that special case, in which $a\theta b$ for all $a,b\in A$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass sure, but $B$ is arbitrary so it is any subuniverse. so by doing it I am considering that special case along with the case $A \not = B $, namely $B \subset A$

Comment: I meant _$a=b$ and $\{b,c\}\subseteq B\implies a\mathrel{\theta}c$_ (and symmetricaly). This is trivial, nevertheless it's a case different from the ones considered.