# Showing $\Theta_{i}$ defined on $\prod _{i\in I}\mathcal{A}_{i}$ is a congruence relation.

Tags: universal-algebra, congruence-relations

I am trying to use the previously asked [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942520/verification-prove-theta-is-a-congruence-on-unary-algebra-underlinea) to help me finish my question. But I have a simple question about their "case 1" (when $a = b$). Why is it that if $a=b$, then $f(a)=f(b)$? Is this by definition or is it assumed f is well-defined? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well $f$ is function, right ?

Comment: @someone You're right! Totally forgot such a trivial definition. This really shows that as one studies mathematics, some simple concepts can be forgotten at moments like this!

Comment: It would be unnatural not to forget anything, but the only thing that matters is to understand things well!